# How to setup a DB2 Stored procedure in GitHub and Jenkins

Tags: git, github, stored-procedures, db2, mainframe

I am working on a IBM DB2 stored procedure. I need to put this in Git repo and access it via Jenkins tool. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to download IBM Data Studio. Don't try this in ISPF. Then, install the Eclipse Git plugin. That will handle getting it into Git. THere's plenty of tutorials on Git out there.

Next, if this is DB2 on z/OS, and you need to deploy it to a z/OS, its going to be difficult to do it through just Jenkins. Urbancode for z/OS handles this quite well. Jenkins will run on z/OS, but you need the Rocket software additions to get it running. Are you also working with Dependency Based Build?